# can we control mat-drawer toggle speed?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

Here's my code, I am just a beginner in the front-end world so please help me out to solve my delay issue in opening and closing the sidebar.

```
<mat-drawer-container autosize>
  <mat-drawer #drawer mode="side" [opened]="isShowing" (mouseout)="toggle()">
    <mat-nav-list>
      <div>
        <div>
          <a mat-list-item class="panel-list-item">
            Marketplace
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-drawer>
  </mat-drawer-container>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can control the speed of the `mat-drawer` toggle animation by using the `animationDuration` property. By default, the duration is set to `250ms`. You can set the duration to a different value in milliseconds, like this:

```html
<mat-drawer-container autosize>
  <mat-drawer #drawer mode="side" [opened]="isShowing" (mouseout)="toggle()" animationDuration="500">
    <mat-nav-list>
      <div>
        <div>
          <a mat-list-item class="panel-list-item">
            Marketplace
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-drawer>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

Comment: Thanks @vihan-gammanpila. Its correct. But its a bit late I have resolved it by reading the mat docs.